# FTP Delete local files if they no longer exist on remote server

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I is it possible using the script below to delete the local files if they no longer exist on the remote directory? Currently this downloads all new files but wont delete files that no longer exist on the ftp server?

```
@Echo Off

REM -- Define File Filter, i.e. files with extension .txt
set FindStrArgs=/x "..*\...*"
REM -- Extract Ftp Script to create List of Files
Set "FtpCommand=ls"
Call:extractFileSection "[Ftp Script 1]" "-">"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
Rem Notepad "%temp%\%~n0.ftp"

REM -- Execute Ftp Script, collect File Names
Set "FileList="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('"Ftp -v -i -s:"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"|Findstr %FindStrArgs%"') Do (
    Call Set "FileList=%%FileList%% "%%A""
)

REM -- Extract Ftp Script to download files that don't exist in local folder
Set "FtpCommand=mget"
For %%A In (%FileList%) Do If Not Exist "%%~A" Call Set "FtpCommand=%%FtpCommand%% "%%~A""
Call:extractFileSection "[Ftp Script 1]" "-">"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
Rem Notepad "%temp%\%~n0.ftp"

For %%A In (%FtpCommand%) Do Echo.%%A

REM -- Execute Ftp Script, download files
ftp -i -s:"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
Del "%temp%\%~n0.ftp"

GOTO:EOF


:extractFileSection StartMark EndMark FileName -- extract a section of file that is defined by a start and end mark
::                  -- [IN]     StartMark - start mark, use '...:S' mark to allow variable substitution
::                  -- [IN,OPT] EndMark   - optional end mark, default is first empty line
::                  -- [IN,OPT] FileName  - optional source file, default is THIS file
:$created 20080219 :$changed 20100205 :$categories ReadFile
:$source http://www.dostips.com
SETLOCAL Disabledelayedexpansion
set "bmk=%~1"
set "emk=%~2"
set "src=%~3"
set "bExtr="
set "bSubs="
if "%src%"=="" set src=%~f0&        rem if no source file then assume THIS file
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('find /n /v "" "%src%"') do (
    if /i "%%B"=="%emk%" set "bExtr="&set "bSubs="
    if defined bExtr if defined bSubs (call echo.%%B) ELSE (echo.%%B)
    if /i "%%B"=="%bmk%"   set "bExtr=Y"
    if /i "%%B"=="%bmk%:S" set "bExtr=Y"&set "bSubs=Y"
)
EXIT /b
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use an ftp client like lftp.  It will give you options to mirror two ftp locations in one line of code (see mirror option).  Also check out the flags:

```
--only-newer
--parallel=10
--delete
```

Comment: Thanks, I need this to be in a batch file though using the current script. I need to run this script on 100 computers

Comment: `cd ‹LOCALPATH›; lftp -u‹USER› -p‹PORT› -e 'mirror --only-newer --delete --verbose=3' sftp://‹HOSTNAME›/‹REMOTEPATH›/` worked great for me, to remove local files not present on remote